# Is there a way to see where a schema validation fails?

Tags: karate

I'm trying to validate a json against a somehow complex 'schema' (defined as in karate docs). The error I'm getting is not so explicit:

`reason: not equal`

How can I check where it actually fails validating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really sorry about that, I'm to blame. I know this won't help you but I'm re-writing the core of Karate right now and this is how a match failure looks like in the improved version:

[image]

Would it be possible for you to create a representative sample of what you have right now (create an issue on GitHub). I would like to see if that is handled better in the future or tweak things right away.